# Nested .Where() causes error. Cannot convey from 'boll'

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, backend

I'm having issues searching for "OriginalValue" which in my case is a country code.
"OriginalValue" can be different types, but I'm searching for country code.

I have to search for all Reports where its OriginalValue is of type CountryCode and where HeadingNumber is equeal to CountryCodeHeadingNummer(which is "34").

The code, however, is not compiling. I get the error:

> CS1503 Argument 2:Cannot convey from 'bool' to System.func<char,bool>'

```
    private IQueryable<Report> SearchCountryCode(ReportSearchFilter search, IQueryable<Report> Reports)
    {
        countryCodeHeadingNumber = "34";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search.CountryCode))
        {
            Reports = Reports.Where(r => r.Headings
                .Any(h => h.OriginalValue
                    .Where(h.HeadingType.HeadingNummer.Equals(countryCodeHeadingNumber))
                .Equals(search.CountryCode)));
        }

        return Reports;
    }
```

Comment: `I get the error: CS1503 Argument 2:Cannot convey from 'boll' to System.func<char,bool>'` I doubt that is the exact error.

Comment: Why are you using `Equals` rather than `Where`?

Comment: The inner `Where` call isn't being passed a lambda expression. You need something with `=>`.

Comment: When i use a where i have to compare it to something. I use to where therfore i need to things. In this case, the first where is looking trough the indput i get from the frontend (the search) and the secend where is that it only have to look torugh the tables where heading type is of  CountryCode

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing this. I just needed to do it, in a diffrent order

```
Reports = Reports 
    .Where(r => af.Headings
       .Where(r => h.HeadingType.HeadingNummer.Equals(countryCodeHeadingNumber))
       .Any(r => r.OriginalValue.Equals(search.CountryCode))
    );
```